# Restricting access to CloudFront by IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I want to restrict bucket access to certain IPs. I know how to create a bucket policy from [Restricting Access to Specific IP Addresses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3).

My question: Can this work with CloudFront? How? Can I allow only certain IPs to access CloudFront?

Comment: to my future self: WAF is super expensive. lambda@edge is probably the better option for most usecases.  list of ips/rules can be stored in s3 to allow for dynamic updates.

Comment: Lambda@edge is $0.60/million invocations. WAF is about $0.60/million requests. So they are actually about the same price. I believe WAF price was recently reduced.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Web Application Firewall is your friend.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-ip-conditions.html

Create your rule with your IP Addresses and rest "WAF" will take care.

You need to apply this to the required CloudFront Distribution.

You can restrict your bucket policies to CloudFront and restrict to your required IP's through CloudFront.

Comment: Is there any issue with high pricing?

Comment: Yes. Based on the estimates, it is a higher pricing. https://calculator.aws/

Answer (score 29):

I have created the custom rule to whitelist IPs and restrict the application with CloudFront distribution with following steps.

Steps:

1. Go to AWS [WAF](https://console.aws.amazon.com/wafv2/home#/intro).
2. Create following IP match conditions under **IP Addresses**.

   1. staging-appname-whitelist-ips
3. Create following rules under **Rules**.

   1. staging-appname-ui-stack-whitelisted-ips

      - with condition (similar for production one)
        [image]
4. Finally create following **Web ACLs**:

   1. staging-appname-acl

      - Please select the correct **CloudFront Distribution**, above created **Rule** and **IP Address** group.
        *. [image]

AWS Resource [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl.html).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

use cloudfront lambda or function to judge X-Forwarded-For Header