# CloudFront and S3 Website Hosting ip restriction bucket policy doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a static website setup with S3 and CloudFront. CloudFront is being used for attaching company SSL Certificate, caching is not needed. At the beginning, our bucket was compeletely public but recently, we are changing the website scope and it will be used internally. So I need to restrict all the access other than our public IPs.

I'm using a bucket policy like ;

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "SourceIP",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SourceIP",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "ip1/32",
                        "ip2/32",
                        "ip3/32",
                        "ip4/32"
                    ]
                },
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I did some research and this kind of request was fulfilled by using WAF in the same case. But I didn't quite understand why WAFless setup (CloudFront + S3 Bucket with Static Website Hosting Enabled + Bucket Policy) is not working. CloudFront is attaching X-Forwarded-For Header to requests to preserve the Source IP, but when I wrote my IP to the bucket policy to allow, I'm receiving access denied. I didn't understand the reason of it.

Any help or explanation will be highly appreciated.
Best Regards.

Comment: **What is the actual problem?** "his kind of request was fulfilled by using WAF in the same case. But I didn't quite understand why? " what does that mean? what does this have to do with WAF?

Comment: Hi @ErmiyaEskandary yes actually, I'm asking why this setup is not working without WAF. I enabled the bucket logs, saw my IP at requests, but still getting Access Denied. I know that WAF option is on my pocket. But my first option would be CloudFront + S3 Bucket + Bucket Policy (If it's possible)

Answer (score 0):

In the [doc: Evaluation logic for conditions with multiple keys or values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html#reference_policies_multiple-conditions-eval):

> If your policy has multiple condition operators or multiple keys
> attached to a single condition operator, the conditions are evaluated
> using a logical AND.

In your case, `"NotIpAddress"` and `"IpAddress"` are evaluated as AND. That's the issue. Split these or just delete `"IpAddress"` part will work.

Comment: Hi, it's not working unfortunately, also in my opinion, it should be operating as AND already. Deny all IPs AND Allow certain ones. Also, I'm using almost same policy with one  IpAdress and one NotIpAdress in the same condition for ECR restriction and it's working without problem. Thank you very much for your time but I think issue is different here.