# Restrict Ip based s3 bucket with CloudFront URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need can access in my website impacted browser and other tool

```json
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybukt-private/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::232914546854:distribution/E1AH6XDXXTZJR7"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybukt-private/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "x.x.x.x.x"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Are you saying that you want to serve S3 content via Amazon CloudFront, restrict the users to a particular IP address? If so, this cannot be done via an S3 bucket policy. See: [Restricting access to CloudFront by IP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46138153/174777)